# How to intercept message from Chatbot in a React component ? (Microsoft botframework-webchat)

Tags: reactjs, botframework, chatbot

I have to run a soundtrack (mp3 file) according to the reply given by Chatbot. So I need to identify the reply that comes from chatbot from my React component (or using pure JS). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly found what you are looking for by searching the Webchat repository on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).

If you search `incoming` you will go to these [lines](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/src/Chat.tsx#L105) which may be interesting for your needs:

```
private handleIncomingActivity(activity: Activity) {
    let state = this.store.getState();
    switch (activity.type) {
        case "message":
            this.store.dispatch<ChatActions>({ type: activity.from.id === state.connection.user.id ? 'Receive_Sent_Message' : 'Receive_Message', activity });
            break;

        case "typing":
            if (activity.from.id !== state.connection.user.id)
                this.store.dispatch<ChatActions>({ type: 'Show_Typing', activity });
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you @Nicolas R**. I changed that handleIncomingActivity() function as follows and send the **activity.text** value in to my chatbot react component as sending data from child(Chat.js) to parent(My react component) using callbacks. Here giveTextForBot() is a callback function which is given to react chatbot component as a prop.

```
Chat.prototype.handleIncomingActivity = function (activity) {
        var state = this.store.getState();
        switch (activity.type) {
            case "message":
                this.store.dispatch({ type: activity.from.id === state.connection.user.id ? 'Receive_Sent_Message' :'Receive_Message' , activity: activity });
                if(activity.from.id === "<appName>"){
                    this.props.giveTextForBot(activity.text);
                   }             
            break;
            case "typing":
                if (activity.from.id !== state.connection.user.id)
                    this.store.dispatch({ type: 'Show_Typing', activity:activity });
                break;
        }
};
```